# Flow: turn off "Unused suppression" error for supress_comment

Tags: javascript, flowtype

The **production** build of my app produces a file that the **development** build does not. I handle the difference in my code like so (simplified example)

```
const manifest = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
  ? require(./production-app-manifest.json')
  : { version: 'dummy development manifest' }
```

Flow therefore (correctly) fails on the second line with 'Required Module not found' when in **development**.

[As the docs suggest here](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex), I suppressed the error like so

```
const manifest = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
  // $FlowFixMe: file not present in development
  ? require(./production-app-manifest.json')
  : { version: 'dummy development manifest' }
```

This solves the problem in **development**.

However, now after a **production** build, I get an `Unused suppression` error because the file *is* present.

This is obviously quite frustrating. I just want to tell flow to completely ignore the line, regardless of if the file is present or not. Can I configure flow to turn off that `Unused suppression` error?

Comment: Why do you need to run Flow on a production build? It's only meant to aid development, it shouldn't be running on your production servers.

Comment: The example is simplified, which probably makes my motivation a little unclear. But basically I'm only talking about running flow under different build configurations that may or may not produce required files. This is not related to production servers - the production build runs on a CI server, where flow is also run as a test step.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to just make it so that line has an error all the time. You could turn the `require` line into this:

`require(('./production-app-manifest.json': string))`

Now, Flow complains that the string passed to `require` is not a literal string, so it's a suppressable error whether or not the file actually exists.